# Zeros and poles from transfer function

Tags: filters, linear-systems, z-transform, transfer-function, digital-filters

I have a transfer function
$$ H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = 1 - 0.5z^{-1} \text{.}$$
I'm interested in zeros and poles.
I know I need to adjust the function to
$$ H(z) = \frac{\prod_i(z-n_i)}{\prod_i(z-p_i)} \text{.}$$
My attempt is as follows:
$$ H(z) = z^{-1} (z - 0.5)$$
So I guess a zero is at $z = 0.5$.
Is it correct?
Moreover, what should I do with $z^{-1}$?
Ignore it?

Thank you.

Comment: why would you ignore it? You've found your zeros, great. What about your poles?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh, I didn't think of that. So there is a pole at $z=0$, right?

Comment: Well, let's try that out! What happens to the original $H(z)$ when you set $z=0$?

Comment: another way to write $z^{-1}$ is $$ \frac{1}{z-0} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the transfer function into the $z$ form, you get
$$ H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{z - 0.5}{z}$$

Then you can immediately see that $Y(z) = z - 0.5$, and $X(z) = z$.  Thus, by inspection, the transfer function has a pole at $z = 0$, and a zero at $z = 0.5$.